# Add item to a google sheet's cell from url?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to pass a URL to a google sheet and have the sheet append a new cell with content taken from a parameter in the URL??

Use case:

In KDE (and other environment as well, perhaps), most applications can  invoke parameterized "Web shortcuts" that launch the browser with a custom-built URi. For instance, from with the pdf reader KDE app "Okular," users can select a portion of text and then invoke, for instance, the Google search shortcut to open up a page with the results of the search. 
The mechanism is simple: users can specify a uri containing the  optional parameter /{@} and the browser will launch with the parameter replaced by the current selection.

For instance, the google shortcut is

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=\{@}&ie=UTF-8
```

Common uses are dictionary queries for foreign languages, technical documentation searches, and so on.

I would like to use this mechanism to build a list of terms while reading documents---simply selecting the term or phrase and choosing the appropriate web shortcut would append it to a google sheet.

Anyone knows if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using IFTTT.

- create a IFTTT web-hook trigger to create your custom URL
- the IFTTT action linked to that trigger is a 'add row to google sheets spreadsheet', which is off-the-shelf

The web-hook part documentation can be found [here](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) and will probably need some tinkering.